# How can I convert a single object of a json string into a .Net object?

Tags: c#, json, .net, deserialization

I have a class like these:

```
class MyDate
{
    int year, month, day;
}
```

I want to fill an object of this class with the data from this JSON string (only from "dateOfBirth"):

```
{
    "firstName":"Markoff",
    "lastName":"Chaney",
    "dateOfBirth":
    {
        "year":"1901",
        "month":"4",
        "day":"30"
    }
}
```

I know the
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(jsonString)`

but I am looking for a way to convert only a single object of a whole JsonString into a .Net object.

I am looking for a DeserializeObject method with a JObject as parameter.

Comment: You already have a `JObject` for the `dateOfBirth` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to parse your json string, only after this you can deserialize any part you need. Your class should be fixed too.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

MyDate myDate = JObject.Parse(json)["dateOfBirth"].ToObject<MyDate>();

public class MyDate
{
    public int year { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyDate
{
    public int year, month, day;
}
Make sure variable should be public



 string str = "{'firstName':'Markoff','lastName':'Chaney','dateOfBirth':{'year':'1901','month':'4','day':'30'}}";
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
            if (data.dateOfBirth != null)
            {
                string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.dateOfBirth);
                MyDate myDate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDate>(strJson);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it could be done without "dynamic", but had forgotten to write it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm)

```
 var result = JObject.Parse(jsonStr).SelectToken("dateOfBirth").ToObject<MyDate>();
```

You need to make your class properties to public